# Staking balance and Reward in cardano

Tags: stake-pool, staking, blockfrost, rewards

I want to get the staking balance and reward in Cardano. I am using the Blockfrost API and I can get the staking and reward amount using the stake address.

However, what I don't understand is that the staking address is not unique for each address. One staking address is associated with several wallet addresses. So, I can't get the exact stake and reward amount for a selected wallet. I can only get them for the selected stake address.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> staking is address is not unique for each address.

Correct, all addresses for a single wallet will have the same staking address.

> One staking address is associated with several wallet addresses.

I do not think that can happen.

Each wallet can have more than one address, but the stake address component for all addresses in a single wallet will be identical.

Comment: I don't  understand, Each wallet can have more than one address. Is it possible? Could you explain in detail?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just realized, my wallet can has several addresses. Now, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have one question. Is there lock for staking balance in cardano?

Comment: Lock? Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: And standard "address" in a wallet is made up of two components; the stake address and the payment credentials. All addresses in a wallet will have the same stake address.

Comment: @Heindrick - Please be vary that while that mode of query is alright for small-scale usage of private wallet, do not use it for projects as a rule- as the converse of question asked is not necessarily true (a stake address can belong to multiple addresses). HD-Wallet is an offchain concept, the blockchain itself does not know of your 'wallet' addresses. An adversary can join their own payment address with a known stake address